# need help removing an IMG and replacing it with text in its position with javascript

Tags: javascript

Im working on a project and a part of it is making an image disapear on hover, and replace that with text in the same location!   I have to do it through javascript.
im very new to front end web development so any help would be great!

```css
.main-img1{
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background-size: 600px 400px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(24, 22, 22);
    position: relative;
    
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: black;
   border-radius: 50px;
}


.img1-text{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   bottom: 8px;
   left: 150px;
```

```html
<section class="main-body">
       <div>
         <img class="main-img1" src="img/automotive.jpg">
          
          <h1 class="img1-text" id="img1text"> Here are some samples of my automotive photography! I specialize in "Rolling Shots" which are caputring a vehicle in motion, while the background and foreground show the motion.</h1>
       </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript that you tried which didn't work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace any element using the "magical" **outerHTML** like this...

First, I gave your image an ID to make javascript operations easier...

```
<img id="I" class="main-img1" src="img/automotive.jpg">
```

Now replace the image with a paragraph of text...

```
I.outerHTML='<p>Well what do you know!</p>';
```

For easy one-line HTML...

```
<img onmouseover="this.outerHTML='<p>Well what do you know!</p>';" class="main-img1" src="img/automotive.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is a very odd thing to do in Javascript. Usually hover states, appearing and disappearing, etc. are handled by CSS.

to do it in js you have to add a mouseover event listener to the image to execute a function to grab the element you want to disappear, add a css class to apply "display: none" to it, grab the element you want to appear and remove a class that adds "display: none" from it.

assuming you have a 'display-none' class on your text element that applies 'display: none' to it, you can do this:

```
const image = document.querySelector('.main-image1')
const text = document.querySelector('.img1-text')
image.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    image.classList.add('display-none')
    text.classList.remove('display-none')
}
```

if you were to do this with css its as simple as

```
.image {
    z-index: 2;
}
.image:hover {
    display: none;
}
.text {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

that way the text is set behind the image and when you hover over the image it disappears. This also has the benefit of when you take your cursor off the image for the image to reappear where js will need to be told explicitly to do that.

Comment: awesome ill give this a shot! and yeaaa, I know its usually done through css, but for the project they want to see if im capable of doing it through javascript!

Comment: @NickThompson Nice! let me know that doesn't work out. If you don't mind, upvote or select as answer if it does :)